# как определить нажал ли пользователь по спрайту или в каком то другом месте

Tags: xcode, swift, spritekit

Добрый день изучаю свифт и паралельно движок spriteKit.

В голову залезла идея зделать игру. например есть 16 квадратов и 8 элементов по паре и среди этих 16 квадратов нужно найти все пары

потихоньку двигаюсь. 
Возникла вот такая проблема

я вывожу 16 элементов на полегон например это спрайт front я их раставил по местам
 в методе я с туториала вставил вот такой код

```
   override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    /* Called when a touch begins */

    let touch = touches.first! as UITouch
    let touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(self)

    //print(touchLocation)

    let body:SKPhysicsBody? = self.physicsWorld.bodyAtPoint(touchLocation)

    //print(self.physicsWorld.bodyAtPoint(touchLocation))


    if body?.node?.name == defaultFrontSprite {
        print("paddle touched")
        firstClicked = true
    } else {
        print("no touch on node")
    }
}
```

Почему то возвращает постоянно отрицательный результат. Вопрос как подружить cпрайт с касанием пальца т.е. как объяснить программе, что если вы нажали именно на спрайт, то делать такое то дело???

я думал создать массив и туда складывать кардинаты каждого cпрайта и при нажатии сравнивать их с кардинатами нажатия, но это я думаю не правильных подход

Answer (score 1):

Вот:

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene
{
    var node = SKSpriteNode()

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView)
{

}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?)
{

    for touch in touches
    {

        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

        if node.containsPoint(location)
        {
            //Пиши сюда свою функцию
        }

    }
}
}
```